# Java Magic Date Assignment

Tags: java

The date June 10, 1960, is special because when we write it in the following format, the month times the day equals the year. 
6/10/60

Design a class named Magic Date(DONE). The class constructor should accept, as integers, values for a month, a day, a year. (DONE). The class should also have a method named isMagic that returns true if date passed to the constructor is magic, or false otherwise ( I have the method Done): 
Write a program that asks the user to enter a month, a day, a two digit year integers(Done) The program should create an instance of the MagicDate class to determine whether the date entered by the user is a magic date. If it is, the program should display a message saying the date is magic. Otherwise it should display a message saying the date is not magic.(Need help with)
What need help with is getting it to return a value. With what I have now it just always returns magic even if the day * month doesn't == the year
This is my code.

```
public class MagicDate 
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    int value;
    public MagicDate(int month, int day, int year) 
    {

    }
         public void isMagic()
         {
             if (month * day == year)
              System.out.println("Magic");
             else 
              System.out.println("Not Magic");
         }





}
```

and the driver

```
public void challenge16()
    {
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        System.out.println("Please enter a month");
        month = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a day");
        day = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a year");
        year = keyboard.nextInt();
        MagicDate magicdate1 = new MagicDate(month, day, year);
        magicdate1.isMagic();

    }
}
```

I'm new this is my first semester so its probably a stupid mistake so I apologize. I also tried the method like this and don't get any returned value.

```
public boolean isMagic()
    if (day * month ==year)
        return True;
    else
        return False
```

Comment: You also need braces around the method body.

Comment: @fge they do exist, they are called `true` and `false`. (lowercase)

Comment: @fge Simply saying they don't exist is very misleading, a better comment would be to explain that they must be lowercase.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments none the less. I was on the wrong track with that being the issue anyways as I simple forgot to store the arguments that are given to the constructor in the instance fields. So the instance fields always have their default values (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MagicDate` class isn't working because you never store the arguments that are given to the constructor in the instance fields. So the instance fields always have their default values (`0`).

If you want to store the passed-in values, you must do that in your code:

```
public MagicDate(int month, int day, int year) 
{
    this.month = month;
    this.day   = day;
    this.year  = year;

    // You might consider initializing `value` here as well, but I
    // have no idea what it's for, so I can't give an example.
}
```

Once you do that, your `isMagic` method should start working, because you're relying on the implicit `this`. That is, because you don't have anything else in scope called `year` (for instance) within that method, when you refer to it, you're referring to `this.year`, which is the field we stored the initial value in in the constructor. That is, your code:

```
public void isMagic()
{
    if (month * day == year)
        System.out.println("Magic");
    else 
        System.out.println("Not Magic");
}
```

is really equivalent to this, which is clearer:

```
public void isMagic()
{
    if (this.month * this.day == this.year)
        System.out.println("Magic");
    else 
        System.out.println("Not Magic");
}
```

(I prefer *always* using the `this.` form, even when -- as in your code above -- it's implied. But you *can* leave it off.)

Comment: excellent i knew I just forgot something silly works like a charm now. sorry for the silly rookie mistake and thanks alot for your time!!!! I tried to upvote you but don't have enough reputation lol sorry

Comment: @TroyWadina You should still be able to mark the answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: @JamoBox: He can't until 15 minutes after the question was posted, which is still a couple of minutes away.

Comment: I will make sure to do so as soon as the option is available.